# how I can build mozilla projects

Tags: linux, browser, build, open-source, mozilla

I found https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/tree/master/b2g Mozilla repositories where have the moz.build file, can anybody help, how I can build this plugin. What are tools I need use for build project with use moz.build ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to build B2G (Firefox OS), then you should follow the procedure documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/B2G_OS/Preparing_for_your_first_B2G_build). But I have to advise you that you're using the wrong repository if that's your objective, since the correct one for B2G should be [this](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/B2G).

In any case, you would need to install the build prerequisites for Linux, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Linux_Prerequisites), by using the following command:

```
wget -O bootstrap.py https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/default/python/mozboot/bin/bootstrap.py && python bootstrap.py
```

Now, if you really wanted to just build the b2g folder in the repository you linked, once you've downloaded and installed the prerequisites, simply issue the following command from the root of `gecko-dev`:

```
./mach build b2g
```

This will invoke *mach*, the build system Mozilla uses, to build the code in the b2g directory.